# How can I draw only a subsection of a Bezier curve in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, bezier

I have a requirement to draw small curved arrows.  I can work out the angle of the arrowhead OK, and I was going to use Beziers to define the path segments.  However, what I would really like to do is to calculate an invisible curved path between start and end, and only stroke the path from a small distance after the start and just before the end.

This would leave a suitable gap between any objects at the start and end points.  Any suggestions?

Comment: How about a gradient with a transparent color in between?

Comment: @DrRiisTab That might make positioning the arrowhead tricky.

Comment: @DrRiisTab:  thanks for the suggestion.  It's possible, because there's a method you could call which works out the tangent and x,y, coords of a point x% along the line.  I just think it would be very fiddly to tailor the Pen to stroke the portion up to that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrows generally don't have insanely messed up curves, they have pretty smooth curves, with the `t` values near the ends behaving as pure cubics (since the Bezier function is dominated by (1-t)³ at the start coordinate, and by t³ at the end coordinate), so near the end points you can "guestimate" the "t" value you need to plug in to get a coordinate near the need by using the cube root:

```
// let's say we want "10% away from the end"
desiredDistance = 0.9;

// then the guestimate for the "t" value is simply the cube root of 0.9
probablyT = Math.pow(desiredDistance, 1/3);

// and the point we want to cut at is at that "t" value
cutPoint = get(probablyT, pts);

// and we can split up the curve into two segments at that "t" value
curves = split(probablyT, pts);

// and then keep the segment we need for the arrow
arrowcurve = curves[0];
```

See http://jsbin.com/dovodibaze/edit?js,output for how well this approximates distances near the end point (and how this clearly only works near the end point you're guessing for =)

With that `probablyT` value you can split your original curve, draw the "first" curve that you get from that split (covering the original t=0 to t=near-the-end segment) and then draw your arrow head at the original end point.

Comment: Got a version in C# not JavaScript?  I'm using WPF.

Comment: I do not, but I fully expect you to be able to read code that is this simple =) (it shouldn't be too much work to WPF-i-fy this if you're familiar with the WPF APIs, the only special calls in the jsbin are to the canvas for drawing a curve and some circles, which shouldn't be too confusing)

Comment: I did update the jsbin with some points to act as "true interval" anchors, so you can play with the computation of `probablyT`and find something that best fits your need. I actually explained this wrong because it's a bit more work than a pure cube root, then again we're programming, not mathematicsing, so "if you 90%, use the 80% cube root" does the trick as far as programming's concerned, even without a mathematical underpinning that explains why >_>;

Comment: I'll have a stab at it at some point and get back to you.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think I may have hit upon a possible solution, after a lot of head scratching.  Say you have a Bezier curve A-B-C-D, where B & C are the control points and A & D the start and end points.  And you want to start and end a standoff distance X from A and D:

1. Generate the Initial Bezier
2. Call  **GetFlattenedPathGeometry** to convert it into a series of small segments
3. Sum up to get the length of the Bezier and divide into X to get the fraction length F from beginning and end
4. Call **PathGeometry.GetPointAtFractionLength** on the original Bezier, passing in F and 1-F.  This will yield a start/end point and a tangent vector for each end of the shortened Bezier
5. Add the start/end point to the tangent vector to get the corresponding control point
6. Generate a new Bezier using these points, which should stand off the original start and end points by X

See any problem with this approach?

Comment: Interesting. Got any implemened code and/or an image to show this?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the late reply.  I don't have any code yet but I will post some when I get around to it.

Comment: I might just be in a position soon to get around to implementing this approach!  I haven't forgotten.  I'll post the code as and when I write it